How do I "say" ok when running "dkms autoinstall" from terminal?
In order to fix my laptop camera I'm following a guide to manually install some third party drivers.
It surely is a trivial problem but bear with me: I have no idea how to continue now that I've run
sudo dkms autoinstall <driver>

The terminal window has shown a message and I don't know how to say OK and continue doing what it tells me.
Please see the attachment.


Hit the Tab key on your keyboard, then press Enter
